# Retrieve data from checkboxes

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox, codeigniter-3

I want to get all the checked data from my table. I'm using checkboxes in my table. When I click "change status", it will change my role status.

But I have problems with retrieving the checkboxes values. In the code below, it failed to update my data. Checkboxes value that I retrieve is NULL. How can I solve this problem?

Model

```
function deaktifRole($id_role,$editBy)
{
    $data = array(
            'update' =>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'updateBy' =>$editBy,
            'flag' => '0'
        );
        
    $this->db->where('id_role',$id_role);
    $this->db->update('tbl_role',$data);
}
```

Controller

```
function deaktifRole()
{
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');


    $editBy = $session_data['username'];
    foreach ($this->input->post['pilih'] as $value) {
        $this->Role->deaktifRole($value->value,$editBy);
    }
    redirect('Home/Role');
    echo '<script>alert("Your form was successfully submitted!");</script>';
}
```

View

```
<div class="x_panel">
              <div class="x_title">
                <h2>Manage Staff Role</small></h2>
                <?php echo form_open_multipart('Home/deaktifRole');?>  
                <div align="right">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add</button>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Change Status</button>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
              <div class="x_content">
                <table id="datatable-checkbox" class="table table-striped table-bordered bulk_action">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th><input type="checkbox" id="check-all" class="flat"></th>
                      <th>No</th>
                      <th>Role</th>
                      <th>Status</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  <?php $j=0; foreach ($RoleList as $rows)
                  {
                    $j++;
                  ?>
                    <tr>
                      <td><input type="checkbox" class="flat" name="pilih[]" value="<?php echo $rows['id_role']; ?>"></td>
                      <td><?php echo $j; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $rows['role']; ?></td>
                      <td>Aktif</td>
                    </tr>
                  <?php } ?> 
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
               <?php echo form_close(); ?>
            </div>
          </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As `$this->input->post('pilih')` is just an associative array, you can access it directly without `->value` properties. Try use this code :

```
foreach ($this->input->post('pilih') as $value) {
    $this->Role->deaktifRole( $value,$editBy );
}
```

Comment: it still retrieve null value

Comment: can you inspect the html rendering page of checkbox. Whether its contains the data or not inside value's attribute

Comment: It feels like, my view didn't post the value. So i got null data. But i don't know the where is the mistake from my code

Comment: Try @mayoori 's answer. `post['pilih']` supposed a function. Not an array.

Comment: yeah, it contains the data. I had inspect it

Comment: Nothing happen, still null

Comment: Can you print r the post, see whether it truly sent the data or not

Comment: when i run the code, the code won't execute the code inside  'foreach'.

Answer (score 0):

use `$this->input->post('pilih');` 
to fetch checkbox data.

Comment: Nothing happen, still null

Comment: inside controller, under `deaktifRole()` method, try printing `$_POST` and check if you get checkbox values?

Comment: i didn't get the value . I just get null value

Comment: there is problem in your form submission, values are not posted in controller. check form submission is done properly or not.

Comment: `$RoleList` is giving records?

Comment: yeah it giving the record from my role list

Comment: the checkbox is inside table with list of role record. when i click the button i want to retrieve id_role value from checked checkbox.

Comment: and its populating checkbox properly?